# What does "バッチい手" mean?

Tags: translation

> そんなバッチい手でボタンを触りたくる…

I know バッチ means batch but what does it mean with 手 here?

It's from this blog btw. https://ameblo.jp/sakurajyuubee/entry-11443690096.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I know バッチ means batch

But it does not.

「ばっちい」 is an informal adjective meaning 「汚{きたな}い」 ("dirty").

https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%B0%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A1%E3%81%84

Thus, 「バッチい手」 means "dirty hand(s)".

> "He keeps on touching/pressing the button with that dirty hand."

This person kept biting his fingernails, touching his beard, pimples, etc., which is why his hands got unclean.

Comment: この場合は「触りたくる」って「触りまくる」のミスではないでしょうか？

Comment: 私自身は「触りたくなる」と読み間違えていたので、回答を編集しましたが、「触りたくる」は”立派な”日本語です。「たくる」には、動詞の連用形に付けて「激しく行う」と意味がありますので。

Comment: あるっちゃありますが、あの文脈ですと、「まくる」しか考えられないじゃないですか(笑)

Comment: 「しか考えられない」と言い切れる文脈ではないというのが自身の見解です。ただ、質問の趣旨とはズレている点ですし、これを最後のコメとさせていただきます。「笑」だけはお返しします。

Comment: @sbkgs4686 `あの文脈ですと、「まくる」しか考えられない...` ☜ えっ、どうしてですか？「そんなバッチい手でボタンを触りたくる」って、おかしくないですよ。「べたべた触る」って感じの意味で使いますよね。あと「塗りたくる」とか。

Comment: 「塗りたくる」など、@Chocolateさんがおっしゃる「たくる」は[この「たくる(4)」](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%9F%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8B/)ですよね？塗りたくるは確かに言いますが、それ以外の言葉にたくるが付いたのをあまり見たことがないような気がします。しかも、そういう解釈をしても、ここの「触りたくる」は、「触りたくなる」ではなく、「触りまくる」に近い意味になると思いますが、、、

Comment: ^ `「触りたくる」は「触りたくなる」ではなく` -- ん？「触りたく**な**る」は全然関係ないですね‥‥  `「触りまくる」に近い意味になる` -- そうですね、近いですね。でも全く同じではないですね、「触りたくる」は「ベタベタと触る」ニュアンスが強いですし。いずれにせよ、ここの「触りたくる」は「触りまくる」のミス・書き間違いなどではないですね。`塗りたくるは確かに言いますが、それ以外の言葉にたくるが付いたのをあまり見たことがない` -- そうですね、見ることはあまりないですね。